How could I generate a bundle with external type declaration merging?
I'm trying to generate a bundled type with declartion merging, but the result doesn't matches my expectation.
For example, here's a simplified code:
import type { JSONSchema7 } from "json-schema";

declare module "json-schema" {
    interface JSONSchema7 {
        additionalProperty1: unknown;
        additionalProperty2?: unknown;
        [key: string]: any;
    }
}

export interface SchemaObject extends JSONSchema7 {}

What I'm trying to do, is to extend the JSONSchema7 interface in json-schema. This solution works well, but not work when there are need to generate the bundle of this.
I've tried rollup-plugin-dts, tsup and some other alternatives, they'll flat all the types in the external module into the bundle, and leaves my additional declartion as is like this:
interface JSONSchema7 {
    originalProperty1: unknown;
    originalProperty2?: unknown;
}

declare module "json-schema" {
    interface JSONSchema7 {
        additionalProperty1: unknown;
        additionalProperty2?: unknown;
        [key: string]: any;
    }
}

export interface SchemaObject extends JSONSchema7 {}

In this result, the declartion merging will not work since it does not match.

I've also tried to import the type by import all of it to see if it will match:
import type * as JSONSchema from "json-schema";

declare module "json-schema" {
    interface JSONSchema7 {
        additionalProperty1: unknown;
        additionalProperty2?: unknown;
        [key: string]: any;
    }
}

export interface SchemaObject extends JSONSchema.JSONSchema7 {}

But seems nothing works.
Is there any existing solution? Or any recommended way to achieve this goal? I hope writing it myself is not the only option left :P
